# Boost C++ Serialization lib missing in xubuntu installation

Tags: boost, boost-serialization, xubuntu

I have xubuntu OS installed on my PC (12.04, Precise Pangolin) and installed C++ boost lib (1.49) using ubuntu's binary repository for boost by issuing the following command in the terminal:

```
       sudo apt-get install libboost-dev
```

The command completed successfully and now I need to use boost serialization lib which is named libboost_serialization for my application. However, I cannot find this in any location under /usr/ in my file system and I wonder why this lib has not been installed automatically when I issued the above apt-get command. Am I supposed install another package separately to get boost serialization library in place in my xubuntu installation? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want this package: http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libboost-serialization-dev.

If you want all Boost sub-packages installed in one operation, you also have a [libboost-all-dev](http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/libboost-all-dev) package.

Comment: Yes, thanks. It helped but I had to use 1.49 at http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libboost-serialization1.49-dev